# Powershell - Missing Output

Tags: powershell, azure-active-directory

I'm new to coding/powershell
I'm trying to get a list of a users AD groups and their Azure Groups
I don't need the output sent to a file or in a fancy table, just a flat list at the prompt

```
$User = Read-Host -Prompt 'Input the userID'
$Email = (Get-ADUser -Identity $User -Properties EmailAddress).EmailAddress

Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership $User | select name
Get-AzureADUserMembership -ObjectId $Email -All $true | select DisplayName
```

it'll output the 1st command fine
when it gets to the 2nd command it'll output a number of blank lines to match what i'm expecting as the output

if i put Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership i get a list of the user's AD memberships then a bunch of blank lines corresponding with the number of Azure groups their in.

if i put Get-AzureADUserMembership first I get a list of the user's Azure memberships then a bunch of blank lines corresponding with the number of AD groups the user is in.

if i comment out either of the commands, the other one works fine.

any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: When `Format-Table` formatting is applied, which happens _implicitly_ if an object has 4 or fewer properties and its type doesn't have associated formatting data, the _first_ object in a collection (potentially even across multiple collections) locks in all display columns based on its properties. If subsequent objects have _different properties_, only those they share with the first one are displayed; if a given object shares none, a blank line is displayed. This is only a _display problem_, as you can verify by piping the objects to `... | Format-List`.
See the linked duplicate for details.